# How to change item of array in Swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui

How to change item of List in Swift ? 
(struct item)

```
@State var people: [Person] = [
        .init(firstName: "Steve",
              lastName: "Jobs", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "jobs"), jobTitle: "Founder of Apple"),
        .init(firstName: "Tim", lastName: "Cook", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cook"), jobTitle: "Apple CEO"),
        .init(firstName: "Jony", lastName: "Ive", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ive"), jobTitle: "Head of Design")
    ]
```

I want to pass the item of this array to another view and that view can modify item (function like class)

I try more way like :

```
@State Person struct
```

Observable Object (not working)
Passthrough (not working)

[this image depict my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9scl.png)

Answer (score 3):

`ObservableObject` should work if used correctly, the core concept of SwiftUI is having a single source of truth. That was where the `Binding` came in, however if you iterate trough a list, you got the value typed `Person` not the desired `Binding<Person>`. You may use indexes through the iteration and pass it to `TextForm` so it can get the original array.

To make a code more readable I suggest to have a viewmodel like

```swift
class PeopleViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var people: [Person] = [
        .init(lastname: "Some", firstname: "Dude"),
        .init(lastname: "Other", firstname: "Dude"),
    ]
}
```

Which you must watch in the view using the `@ObservedObject` wrapper.

```swift
struct PeopleList: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = PeopleViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.people.indices) { index in
                TextForm(viewModel: self.viewModel, index: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And have the `TextForm` have the index end the viewmodel instance.

```swift
struct TextForm: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PeopleViewModel
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("textField", text: self.$viewModel.people[index].firstname)
            Text(self.viewModel.people[index].firstname)
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want to omit the viewmodel just pass the binding trough indexing.

```swift
            List(people.indices) { index in
                TextForm(item: self.$people[index])
            }
```

```swift
struct TextForm: View {

    @Binding var item: Person

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("textField", text: self.$item.firstname)
            Text(self.item.firstname)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the viewModel idea (very Android-esque). However, if pass my viewModel down to where I want to change it, the viewModel is changed, but if I immediately show the component that lists the contents of the model, the new data isn't there. I have to wind back up and go back down to get the updated model to display. BTW- the viewModel contents are in the Picker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a `Binding`.
E.g:

```
struct MySecondView: View {
    @Binding var people: [People]    

    var body: some View { ... }

    func modifyArray() { /* Do whatever you need here */ }
}
```

And pass it to that view when initializing it in your other view like:

```
MySecondView(people: self.$people)
```

Comment: You see the image I posted on it

Answer (score 0):

one thing that almost no one writes about in the ObservableObject solution - it is best that the item in the array will be struct instead of class,

when a struct member (var) change it's value it is considered as a change to the containing struct, and achange to the containing struct (the array element) is considered as a change to the whole array (and therefor a change to the published object) - and this small change will cause the view to re render

so to make a short story long, here are 2 fully working code examples, one does not work (where Episode is Class) and the other is working (where Episode is Struct)

**this code will not update the View** as expected only because the Episode entity is defined as Class:

```
struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SeasonScreen()
    }
}

// model class that represents episode data
class Episode: Identifiable
{
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    var watched: Bool
    
    init(name: String, watched: Bool)
    {
        id = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.watched = watched
    }
}

// dummy server api that returns the episodes array
struct ServerAPI
{
    static func getAllEpisodes(showId: String, seasonId: String, completion: @escaping([Episode]) -> ())
    {
        let dummyResponse: [Episode] = [Episode(name: "Episode 1", watched: true), Episode(name: "Episode 2", watched: false)]
        completion(dummyResponse)
    }
}

// class that holds (and publish changes on) the episodes array
class SeasonEpisodes: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var episodesRow: [Episode] = []

    init()
    {
        ServerAPI.getAllEpisodes(showId: "Friends", seasonId: "Season 2", completion: { episodes in
            self.episodesRow = episodes
        })
    }
}

// main screen view that contains episodes array object and observe changes on it
struct SeasonScreen: View
{
    @ObservedObject var seasonEpisodes: SeasonEpisodes = SeasonEpisodes()
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            if(self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow.count > 0)
            {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)
                {
                    HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.center, spacing: 60.0, content: {
                        ForEach(self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow.indices) { episodeIndex in
                            EpisodeButton(seasonEpisodes: self.seasonEpisodes, episodeIndex: episodeIndex)
                                .padding(40)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.white)
    }
}

// ui view to represent episode button
struct EpisodeButton: View
{
    @ObservedObject var seasonEpisodes: SeasonEpisodes
    let episodeIndex: Int
    
    
    var body: some View
    {
        let watchedText = self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow[episodeIndex].watched ? "Watched" : ""
        
        Button(action: {
            // although the change occurr on the observed object and it causes the SeasonScreen
            // to re render, and therefor re render this button view, that should receive the
            // new watched value - it doesn't work
            self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow[episodeIndex].watched = !self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow[episodeIndex].watched
            print("episode new watched value: \(self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow[episodeIndex].watched)")
        }, label: {
            Text("\(self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow[episodeIndex].name) \(watchedText)")
                .frame(width: 420, height: 224)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        })
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .padding()
    }
}
```

tapping on the buttons will produce these log lines that confirm the value is changing (although view is not re-render):

```
episode new watched value: false
episode new watched value: true
episode new watched value: false
```

and **this code will work** as expected and reflect the new changed value on the view just because i replaced the Episode entity from Class to Struct:

```
struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SeasonScreen()
    }
}

// model class that represents episode data
struct Episode: Identifiable  // <--- this is the only change to make it work
{
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    var watched: Bool
    
    init(name: String, watched: Bool)
    {
        id = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.watched = watched
    }
}

// dummy server api that returns the episodes array
struct ServerAPI
{
    static func getAllEpisodes(showId: String, seasonId: String, completion: @escaping([Episode]) -> ())
    {
        let dummyResponse: [Episode] = [Episode(name: "Episode 1", watched: true), Episode(name: "Episode 2", watched: false)]
        completion(dummyResponse)
    }
}

// class that holds (and publish changes on) the episodes array
class SeasonEpisodes: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var episodesRow: [Episode] = []

    init()
    {
        ServerAPI.getAllEpisodes(showId: "Friends", seasonId: "Season 2", completion: { episodes in
            self.episodesRow = episodes
        })
    }
}

// main screen view that contains episodes array object and observe changes on it
struct SeasonScreen: View
{
    @ObservedObject var seasonEpisodes: SeasonEpisodes = SeasonEpisodes()
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            if(self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow.count > 0)
            {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)
                {
                    HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.center, spacing: 60.0, content: {
                        ForEach(self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow.indices) { episodeIndex in
                            EpisodeButton(seasonEpisodes: self.seasonEpisodes, episodeIndex: episodeIndex)
                                .padding(40)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.white)
    }
}

// ui view to represent episode button
struct EpisodeButton: View
{
    @ObservedObject var seasonEpisodes: SeasonEpisodes
    let episodeIndex: Int
    
    
    var body: some View
    {
        let watchedText = self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow[episodeIndex].watched ? "Watched" : ""
        
        Button(action: {
            // this time the new watched value reflects on the view
            self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow[episodeIndex].watched = !self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow[episodeIndex].watched
            print("episode new watched value: \(self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow[episodeIndex].watched)")
        }, label: {
            Text("\(self.seasonEpisodes.episodesRow[episodeIndex].name) \(watchedText)")
                .frame(width: 420, height: 224)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        })
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .padding()
    }
}
```